# How do I get my custom UserControl to set the colour of a nested ellipse?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I've been poking around at various links and I can't tell if I need a DependencyProperty, INotifyPropertyChanged, some kind of binding or something else.

I'm working on my first UserControl for re-use purposes.  I have a UserControl that contains a label and a coloured ellipse.  I want to be able to set the Ellipse colour in the windows XAML at design time.  I have the following code in Visual Studio 2013 Community:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DMS2.LegendLabel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Ellipse Name="Indicator" Height="10" Width="10" Margin="5" Fill="Aqua"/>
    <Label> value </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

```
namespace DMS2
{
    public partial class LegendLabel : UserControl
    {      
        public LegendLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Brush ellipse_color = Brushes.Azure;

        public Brush LegendColor
        {
            get { return ellipse_color;  }
            set { ellipse_color = value; Indicator.Fill = ellipse_color; }
        }
    }
}


<Window x:Class="DMS2.ReportMonitor"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:custom_controls="clr-namespace:DMS2"
        Title="Report Monitor" Height="450" Width="850">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="MainPanel">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="ButtonPanel">
            <Button Height="25" Margin="30,0"> Refresh List</Button>
            <CheckBox Margin="10"> show Reports From All Users</CheckBox>
            <Grid Margin="10" Width="300">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <custom_controls:LegendLabel LegendColor="Red">Pending</custom_controls:LegendLabel>
                <custom_controls:LegendLabel Grid.Column="1" LegendColor="Green">Viewed</custom_controls:LegendLabel>
                <custom_controls:LegendLabel Grid.Column="2" LegendColor="Blue">Active</custom_controls:LegendLabel>
                <Label Grid.Row="1">Done</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">Error</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">Closed</Label>
            </Grid>
            <Button Height="25" Margin="30,0">Close</Button>

        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Using the LegendColor as shown below has now effect.  How can I make the following work?

```
<custom_controls:LegendLabel LegendColor="Red">Pending</custom_controls:LegendLabel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would typically use a `DependencyProperty` here (snippet: `propdp`).

```
    public Brush LegendColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(LegendColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LegendColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LegendColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LegendColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(LegendLabel), new PropertyMetadata(null, HandleBrushChange));
```

Once you have it, you would perform your set in the `PropertyChanged` handler (the second argument to the metadata):

```
private static void HandleBrushChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   LegendLabel local = (LegendLabel)d;

   local.Indicator.Fill = e.NewValue as Brush;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where the second 'local' is coming from?

Comment: Thank you.  I guess the 0d in the PropertyMetadata constructor is also incorrect.  I changed that Brushes.Aqua so that it would compile.  It compiles now but I still don't get the result I'm looking for.  The ellipse doesn't show with any color.

Comment: @Hugh Yep, also a mistake from me (I copy pasted that from a `double` DP). Normally I would initialize to `null`, but a standard brush is reasonable. Can you verify that the `Change` event is handled? You may also need to get the "initial" state in the `Loaded` event.